# Handling sysnonyms in stanford classifier

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Is it possible to handle synonyms or other specific two or more words to be considered as a single feature in a bag of words model in stanford classifier?

For instance :
I would want would and could to be considered as a single feature .

Comment: @tttthomasssss is it harvard flux compensator or capacitor ? Could not find a google search reference to 'harvard flux compensator' .

Comment: @Coffee, I am building a classifier which makes a single feature from a specific set of words/ phrases .For example - 'hi','hey','hello' should be treated as single feature.

Comment: @user2256866 - ignore the "harvard " line above, please. it was jest

Comment: @user2256866 bugger me - damn right sir!

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand your question. Please be a bit more specific about what you are trying to classify.

But generally, you can always transform your input before giving it to any classifier. I.e. replace "hey, could i help you" with "X, Y I help you" where X is a placeholder for the group {hi, hey, hello, ...}.

These groups are sometimes called "synsets", e.g. in WordNet (http://wordnet.princeton.edu/). Here's the synsets of "hello" in WordNet: [1] If this is helpful, there's APIs to access WordNet.

You can of course just manually create these word groups as well. Keep in mind though that there's a lot of ambigious words where assigning one of these groups is quite hard.

[1] http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=hello&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=